# How to use the mlab iso_surface module in a Mayavi app

Tags: enthought, mayavi

I'm trying to build a simple Mayavi script application which utilises the mlab `iso_surface` module.

However, when I run my app it throws up two windows, one showing my mayavi iso_surface plot and the other showing a blank "Edit properties" window. It seems that the mayavi scene is not being displayed in the specified view layout for the "Edit properties" window.

So my question is: *Why is the mayavi iso_surface scene not appearing in the view layout, and how do I get it in there?*

A simple test script which displays this behaviour is pasted below. I am using Canopy version: 2.1.1.3504 (64 bit), python 3.5.2 on a Windows 10 system.

[Note: I have modified my original question to include another question. How do I update the 's' data with the input from a Range object (mult_s)? I have had a go at doing this below, but with no success. It throws up: `TraitError: Cannot set the undefined 's' attribute of a 'ArraySource' object.`]

```
class Isoplot1(HasTraits):
    scene = Instance(MlabSceneModel, ())
    mult_s = Range(1, 5, 1)

    @on_trait_change('scene.activated')
    def _setup(self):
        # Create x, y, z, s data
        L = 10.
        x, y, z = np.mgrid[-L:L:101j, -L:L:101j, -L:L:101j]
        self.s0 = np.sqrt(4 * x ** 2 + 2 * y ** 2 + z ** 2)        

        # create the data pipeline
        self.src1 = mlab.pipeline.scalar_field(x, y, z, self.s0)

        # Create the plot
        self.plot1 = self.scene.mlab.pipeline.iso_surface(
            self.src1, contours=[5, ], opacity=0.5, color=(1, 1, 0)
        )

    @on_trait_change('mult_s')
    def change_s(self):
        self.src1.set(s=self.s0 * self.mult_s)

    # Set the layout
    view = View(Item('scene', 
                     editor=SceneEditor(scene_class=MayaviScene),
                     height=400, width=600, show_label=False),
                HGroup('mult_s',),
                resizable=True
                )

isoplot1 = Isoplot1()
isoplot1.configure_traits()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use `self.scene.mlab.pipeline.scalar_field` instead of `mlab.pipeline.scalar_field` this should not happen.

In general, you should avoid creating any visualization in the initializer.  Instead you should always setup the scene when the `scene.activated` event is fired.   To be safe for uses with raw mlab you should rewrite your code as follows.

```
from mayavi import mlab
from traits.api import HasTraits, Instance, on_trait_change
from traitsui.api import View, Item
from mayavi.core.ui.api import MayaviScene, SceneEditor, MlabSceneModel
import numpy as np

class Isoplot1(HasTraits):
    scene = Instance(MlabSceneModel, ())

    @on_trait_change('scene.activated')
    def _setup(self):
        # Create x, y, z, s data
        L = 10.
        x, y, z = np.mgrid[-L:L:101j, -L:L:101j, -L:L:101j]
        s = np.sqrt(4 * x ** 2 + 2 * y ** 2 + z ** 2)

        # create the data pipeline
        self.src1 = mlab.pipeline.scalar_field(x, y, z, s)

        # Create the plot
        self.plot1 = self.scene.mlab.pipeline.iso_surface(
            self.src1, contours=[5, ], opacity=0.5, color=(1, 1, 0)
        )

    # Set the layout
    view = View(Item('scene', 
                     editor=SceneEditor(scene_class=MayaviScene),
                     height=400, width=600, show_label=False),
                resizable=True
                )

isoplot1 = Isoplot1()
isoplot1.configure_traits()
```

You probably already know this but just in case you can also take a look at some of the other [mayavi interactive examples](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/examples.html#interactive-examples) in the documentation.

Comment: Thx for the fast response Prabhu, your modified code works for me.
I had actually based my code attempt on the example provided at http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/building_applications.html but I see now there is a warning below to use the approach you have suggested above.